# Need Help in selecting from 2 tables POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql-9.2

need help regarding the below scenario......

### Table 1    name : function

### f_id     |f_name

10001    |Function 1 
10002    |Function 2 
10003    |Function 3

### Table 2    name : function_user

### fu_id    |fu_user

10001    |T_User1
10001    |T_User2
10001    |T_User3
10002    |G_User1
10002    |G_User2
10002    |G_User3
10002    |G_User4
10002    |G_User5
10002    |G_User6
10003    |X_User1
10003    |X_User2

### Result Needed

### f_id     |fu_user

10001    |T_User1

```
     |T_User2

     |T_User3
```

10002    |G_User1

```
     |G_User2

     |G_User3

     |G_User4

     |G_User5

     |G_User6
```

10003    |X_User1

```
     |X_User2
```

Immediate help would be highly appreciated......
:)

Answer (score 0):

Select function.f_id, function_user.fu_user from function right join function_user on f_id=fu_id

Comment: it will select function.f_id for all the rows. I need function.f_id for the first occurrence only....... dont want function.f_id returned for all the rows

Comment: I know it can be done using procedure, But i need query for that..... anyone please....

Answer (score 0):

in PostgreSQL 9.2 there is a function string_agg(expression, delimiter). May be it will suites your goal?
The query will looks something like:

```
select f_id ,string_agg(fu_user,'\n') from function join function_user on f_id=fu_id group by f_id {order_if_you_need};
```

you can play with the delimiter to adjust the format but it expected to be a single character

Comment: It looks ok... But still.....,
fu_user will be selected as a single field ryt?(with delimiter)...
is there any other way i will get it as multiple rows......
Not possible i think..... i think i should proceed with custom function... :(